# cucumber sending mail after running one scheduled run

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using Ruby+Cucumber for my API automation and i have almost 500+ scenarios. My scripts will run and finally gives one html file as output(test report). We have planned to schedule this 500+ cases to run daily thro' a batch file with windows scheduler. We have a separate windows server for this task alone and we run the scripts on that VM machine with the help of scheduler. But to see the execution results, we see coming after next day and someone has to connect to the server and see the result file (html).

I am not sure how to send the output (test result) in the mail with the ruby script. (i know sending mail with ruby script). But my question is, i want all my script to run and finally i need my test results to be send in mail to a group. I tried with 'env.rb' file by having 'After' keyword. But This is executing after each scenario. So mail send after executing each scenario.

So can anyone help me how to send a one final mail after running once cycle of execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cucumber documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#global-hooks) suggests using "[`Kernel#at_exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) for global teardown":

```
at_exit do
  # send some mail
end
```

Comment: super...i got it exactly what i want. Thanks much.